# Swift "Cannot convert value of type ' ' to type ' String '

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that I am obviously doing something wrong, but i don't know how to fix this issue.
I am getting Int values from my firebase database and want to show them in a Text Label.

But either I am getting an error, saying that my values are nil or that my values cannot be converted.

Maybe someone can figure out how to achieve what I want to do.

I get the error at following line:

```
 cell.itemValueLabel.text = ahpPrio
```

Thanks for your help everybody. :)

```
//
//  AHPfinalPreferencesViewController.swift
//  ProLabArtv2
//
//  Created by Manu on 30.06.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Manuel Knott. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class AHPfinalPreferencesViewController: UIViewController {


// MARK: - Properties
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var ahpPrios =  [AHPPriority]()
        
        let itemsForRating = ["Ability", "Accuracy", "Planning", "Quality of Work", "Productivity", "Punctuality", "Responsibility", "Job_Knowledge", "Creativity", "Initiative", "Job Commitment", "Organization Loyalty", "Supervisor Loyalty", "Dependability", "Honesty", "Cooperation", "Attitude",  "Communication_Skils",  "Judgment", "Interpersonal Relationship"]
        
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UserService.ahpPref(for: User.current) { (ahpPrios) in
          self.ahpPrios = ahpPrios
          self.tableView.reloadData()
      }

    }
    
// MARK: - Element Style
    
func configureTableView() {
        // remove separators for empty cells
       tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        // remove separators from cells
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }
    
    
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    
extension AHPfinalPreferencesViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            let ahpPrio = ahpPrios[indexPath.row]

            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

            print(ahpPrios)

        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return ahpPrios.count
        }


        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            let ahpPrio = ahpPrios[indexPath.row]
            let ratingItemT = itemsForRating[indexPath.row]

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AHPPrefTableViewCell") as! AHPPrefTableViewCell
            
//            cell.update(ahpPrio)
            
            cell.itemPrefLabel.text = ratingItemT
            cell.itemValueLabel.text = ahpPrio
                
//            cell.nameLabel.text = ahpPrios[indexPath.row].memberName
          
            

                return cell
            }
        }

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

extension AHPfinalPreferencesViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return 80
    }
}
```

```
//
//  AHPService.swift
//  ProLabArtv2
//
//  Created by Manu on 02.07.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Manuel Knott. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseUI
import FirebaseAuth


struct AHPService {
    
      static let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    

    static func createAHP(forUser firUser: String) {
        
        let ajkpXc:Int = GLajkpXc
        let ajkpXijr: Int = GLajkpXijr
        let ajkpXqpa: Int = GLajkpXqpa
        let ajkpXcoj: Int = GLajkpXcoj
        let ajkpXlos: Int = GLajkpXlos
        let ajkpXiracc: Int = GLajkpXiracc
        let ajkpXdph: Int = GLajkpXdph
        let cXijr: Int = GLcXijr
        let cXqpa: Int = GLcXqpa
        let cXcoj: Int = GLcXcoj
        let cXlos: Int = GLcXlos
        let cXiracc: Int = GLcXiracc
        let cXdph: Int = GLcXdph
        let ijrXqpa: Int = GLijrXqpa
        let ijrXcoj: Int = GLijrXcoj
        let ijrXlos: Int = GLijrXlos
        let ijrXiracc: Int = GLijrXiracc
        let ijrXdph: Int = GLijrXdph
        let qpaXcoj: Int = GLqpaXcoj
        let qpaXlos: Int = GLqpaXlos
        let qpaXiracc: Int = GLqpaXiracc
        let qpaXdph: Int = GLqpaXdph
        let cojXlos: Int = GLcojXlos
        let cojXiracc: Int = GLcojXiracc
        let cojXdph: Int = GLcojXdph
        let losXiracc: Int = GLlosXiracc
        let losXdph: Int = GLlosXdph
        let iraccXdph: Int = GLiraccXdph
      
      let timestamp = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    
  
    
      
        let ahpPriorities = AHPPriority(ajkpXc: ajkpXc, ajkpXijr: ajkpXijr, ajkpXqpa: ajkpXqpa, ajkpXcoj: ajkpXcoj, ajkpXlos: ajkpXlos, ajkpXiracc: ajkpXiracc, ajkpXdph: ajkpXdph, cXijr: cXijr, cXqpa: cXqpa, cXcoj: cXcoj, cXlos: cXlos, cXiracc: cXiracc, cXdph: cXdph, ijrXqpa: ijrXqpa, ijrXcoj: ijrXcoj, ijrXlos: ijrXlos, ijrXiracc: ijrXiracc, ijrXdph: ijrXdph, qpaXcoj: qpaXcoj, qpaXlos: qpaXlos, qpaXiracc: qpaXiracc, qpaXdph: qpaXdph, cojXlos: cojXlos, cojXiracc: cojXiracc, cojXdph: cojXdph, losXiracc: losXiracc, losXdph: losXdph, iraccXdph: iraccXdph)
        
        let currentUser = User.current
        
        let dict = ahpPriorities.dictValue
        
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("AHPRatings").child(currentUser.uid).childByAutoId()

        ref.setValue(dict)
}}
```

```
//  UserService.swift
//  ProLabArtv2
//
//  Created by Manu on 20.05.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Manuel Knott. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth.FIRUser
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseUI
import FirebaseAuth


struct UserService {
    
    static let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

static func ahpPref(for user: User, completion: @escaping ([AHPPriority]) -> Void) {
        
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("AHPRatings").child(user.uid)
        

                  ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                               guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
                                  return completion([])
                               }

                    let ahpPrios = snapshot.reversed().compactMap(AHPPriority.init)
                    completion(ahpPrios)
        })
    }

        
}
```

```
//
//  AHPPriority.swift
//  ProLabArtv2
//
//  Created by Manu on 21.06.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Manuel Knott. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase.FIRDataSnapshot

class AHPPriority {
    
    var key: String?
    
    let creationDate: Date
    let ajkpXc: Int
    let ajkpXijr: Int
    let ajkpXqpa: Int
    let ajkpXcoj: Int
    let ajkpXlos: Int
    let ajkpXiracc: Int
    let ajkpXdph: Int
    let cXijr: Int
    let cXqpa: Int
    let cXcoj: Int
    let cXlos: Int
    let cXiracc: Int
    let cXdph: Int
    let ijrXqpa: Int
    let ijrXcoj: Int
    let ijrXlos: Int
    let ijrXiracc: Int
    let ijrXdph: Int
    let qpaXcoj: Int
    let qpaXlos: Int
    let qpaXiracc: Int
    let qpaXdph: Int
    let cojXlos: Int
    let cojXiracc: Int
    let cojXdph: Int
    let losXiracc: Int
    let losXdph: Int
    let iraccXdph: Int

    
    init(ajkpXc: Int, ajkpXijr: Int, ajkpXqpa: Int, ajkpXcoj: Int, ajkpXlos: Int, ajkpXiracc: Int, ajkpXdph: Int, cXijr: Int, cXqpa: Int, cXcoj: Int, cXlos: Int, cXiracc: Int, cXdph: Int, ijrXqpa: Int, ijrXcoj: Int, ijrXlos: Int, ijrXiracc: Int, ijrXdph: Int, qpaXcoj: Int,  qpaXlos: Int,   qpaXiracc: Int,  qpaXdph: Int, cojXlos: Int, cojXiracc: Int, cojXdph: Int, losXiracc: Int, losXdph: Int, iraccXdph: Int) {
        
                self.creationDate = Date()
                self.ajkpXc = ajkpXc
                self.ajkpXijr = ajkpXijr
                self.ajkpXqpa = ajkpXqpa
                self.ajkpXcoj = ajkpXcoj
                self.ajkpXlos = ajkpXlos
                self.ajkpXiracc = ajkpXiracc
                self.ajkpXdph = ajkpXdph
                self.cXijr = cXijr
                self.cXqpa = cXqpa
                self.cXcoj = cXcoj
                self.cXlos = cXlos
                self.cXiracc = cXiracc
                self.cXdph =  cXdph
                self.ijrXqpa = ijrXqpa
                self.ijrXcoj = ijrXcoj
                self.ijrXlos = ijrXlos
                self.ijrXiracc =  ijrXiracc
                self.ijrXdph =  ijrXdph
                self.qpaXcoj = qpaXcoj
                self.qpaXlos = qpaXlos
                self.qpaXiracc =   qpaXiracc
                self.qpaXdph = qpaXdph
                self.cojXlos = cojXlos
                self.cojXiracc = cojXiracc
                self.cojXdph = cojXdph
                self.losXiracc =   losXiracc
                self.losXdph = losXdph
                self.iraccXdph = iraccXdph
        
        
    }

    var dictValue: [String: Any] {
   let createdAgo = creationDate.timeIntervalSince1970
    
        return ["created_at" : createdAgo,
        "ajkpXc": ajkpXc,
        "ajkpXijr ": ajkpXijr,
        "ajkpXqpa": ajkpXqpa,
        "ajkpXcoj": ajkpXcoj,
        "ajkpXlos ": ajkpXlos,
        "ajkpXiracc ": ajkpXiracc,
        "ajkpXdph": ajkpXdph,
        "cXijr": cXijr,
        "cXqpa": cXqpa,
        "cXcoj": cXcoj,
        "cXlos": cXlos,
        "cXiracc": cXiracc,
        "cXdph": cXdph,
        "ijrXqpa": ijrXqpa,
        "ijrXcoj": ijrXcoj,
        "ijrXlos": ijrXlos,
        "ijrXiracc": ijrXiracc,
        "ijrXdph": ijrXdph,
        "qpaXcoj": qpaXcoj,
        "qpaXlos": qpaXlos,
        "qpaXiracc": qpaXiracc,
        "qpaXdph": qpaXdph,
        "cojXlos": cojXlos,
        "cojXiracc": cojXiracc,
        "cojXdph": cojXdph,
        "losXiracc": losXiracc,
        "losXdph": losXdph,
        "iraccXdph": iraccXdph ]
     
}
    
    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any],
    
    let createdAgo = dict["created_at"] as? TimeInterval,
    let ajkpXc = dict["ajkpXc"] as? Int,
    let ajkpXijr = dict["ajkpXijr"] as? Int,
    let ajkpXqpa = dict["ajkpXqpa"] as? Int,
    let ajkpXcoj = dict["ajkpXcoj"] as? Int,
    let ajkpXlos = dict["ajkpXlos"] as? Int,
    let ajkpXiracc = dict["ajkpXiracc"] as? Int,
    let ajkpXdph = dict["ajkpXdph"] as? Int,
    let cXijr = dict["cXijr"] as? Int,
    let cXqpa = dict["cXqpa"] as? Int,
    let cXcoj = dict["cXcoj"] as? Int,
    let cXlos = dict["cXlos"] as? Int,
    let cXiracc = dict["cXiracc"] as? Int,
    let cXdph = dict["cXdph"] as? Int,
    let ijrXqpa = dict["ijrXqpa"] as? Int,
    let ijrXcoj = dict["ijrXcoj"] as? Int,
    let ijrXlos = dict["ijrXlos"] as? Int,
    let ijrXiracc = dict["ijrXiracc"] as? Int,
    let ijrXdph = dict["ijrXdph"] as? Int,
    let qpaXcoj = dict["qpaXcoj"] as? Int,
    let qpaXlos = dict["qpaXlos"] as? Int,
    let qpaXiracc = dict["qpaXiracc"] as? Int,
    let qpaXdph = dict["qpaXdph"] as? Int,
    let cojXlos = dict["cojXlos"] as? Int,
    let cojXiracc = dict["cojXiracc"] as? Int,
    let cojXdph = dict["cojXdph"] as? Int,
    let losXiracc = dict["losXiracc"] as? Int,
    let losXdph = dict["losXdph"] as? Int,
    let iraccXdph = dict["iraccXdph"] as? Int

     else {return nil}
        
        
        self.key = snapshot.key
        self.creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: createdAgo)
        self.ajkpXc = ajkpXc
        self.ajkpXijr = ajkpXijr
        self.ajkpXqpa = ajkpXqpa
        self.ajkpXcoj = ajkpXcoj
        self.ajkpXlos = ajkpXlos
        self.ajkpXiracc = ajkpXiracc
        self.ajkpXdph = ajkpXdph
        self.cXijr = cXijr
        self.cXqpa = cXqpa
        self.cXcoj = cXcoj
        self.cXlos = cXlos
        self.cXiracc = cXiracc
        self.cXdph =  cXdph
        self.ijrXqpa = ijrXqpa
        self.ijrXcoj = ijrXcoj
        self.ijrXlos = ijrXlos
        self.ijrXiracc =  ijrXiracc
        self.ijrXdph =  ijrXdph
        self.qpaXcoj = qpaXcoj
        self.qpaXlos = qpaXlos
        self.qpaXiracc =   qpaXiracc
        self.qpaXdph = qpaXdph
        self.cojXlos = cojXlos
        self.cojXiracc = cojXiracc
        self.cojXdph = cojXdph
        self.losXiracc =   losXiracc
        self.losXdph = losXdph
        self.iraccXdph = iraccXdph
        }

}
```

Comment: You cannot assign a non-text *object* to a text field. You can only assign *text* (a string). In other words, there's an array of objects `var ahpPrios =  [AHPPriority]()` and the code reads one of those objects `let ahpPrio = ahpPrios[indexPath.row]` and attempts to assign the whole object to a single text field `cell.itemValueLabel.text = ahpPrio` which doesn't make sense. You would need to get *one* of the properties of that object and assign it `cell.itemValueLabel.text = ahpPrio.some_property`. Additionally there's a structure *within* a structure so you need to coordinate that as well.

Answer (score 3):

The error clearly states that there is a mismatch of types here. `cell.itemValueLabel.text` is of type `String` so for setting its value you have to provide a `String`. Whereas you are providing the property `ahpPrio` which is not a `String`, it's of the type `AHPPriority`. So to fix it you need to do something like:

```
cell.itemValueLabel.text = "\(ahpPrio.propertyName)" // where propertyName denotes a property in `AHPPriority`
```

Comment: Hey @Frankenstein, thanks for your fast answer! I updated the question cause I forgot to share the AHPPriority Class. My goal is, to iterate over all of those items. So calling a specific propertyName doesn't work in this case I guess. 

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi @Schaedel420 you should be aware by now that in SO 1 post should deal with a single problem. And this post should deal with fixing the error you've mentioned in OP. If you've a follow-up question do post it as another question and comment the link below will try to help you out.

Comment: @Schaedel420 If your goal is to iterate over the properties of a structure *within another structure* you've not included any code in your question that would attempt to do that. Perhaps you should clarify and update your question so are can focus answers on a specific issue.